# Creating web-browser playable webm files with vp8 SDK?

Tags: c++, matroska, webm, vp8, libvpx

I'm using the vp8 SDK (www.webmproject.org) to create a vp8-encoded video file. However, the SDK sample produces an IVF file, which the browser doesn't play.

I know the webm format is a matroska container so I guess I should store the video data in that format, but the mkv format specification is lengthy and complex and I don't think I should reinvent the wheel by figuring it out by myself.

So I would like to know if someone can recommend a sample of how to encode and produce a playable webm vp8 file.
If there is no such sample (as my searches on google suggest) at least point me to a simple and usable matroska lib which is proven to work for the browsers.

Comment: libvpx already includes functions to convert IVF frames into webm file. You could check codes in [libvpx/vpxenc.c](https://code.google.com/p/webm/source/browse/vpxenc.c?repo=libvpx).